# ExecuteNonQuery not updating output parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using ExecuteNonQuery to insert a record in a database and return the id for the new record. It inserts fine, but the output parameter does not get updated.

Tried executing the stored procedure in SSMS and it worked fine. Only has an issue when executing it with ExecuteNonQuery.

Included is all of the code that is used to attempt the insert.

```
        public int InsertPurchaseOrder(IPurchaseOrder po)
        {
            int returnId = 0;
            int returnCount = 0;

            List<IParam> parms = ParameterFactory.CreateListInstance();

            parms.Add(ParameterFactory.CreateParameter("@Timestamp", po.Timestamp, SqlDbType.Timestamp, ParameterDirection.Output));
            parms.Add(ParameterFactory.CreateParameter("@Status", po.Status, SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Input));
            parms.Add(ParameterFactory.CreateParameter("@Subtotal", po.Subtotal, SqlDbType.Money, ParameterDirection.Input));
            parms.Add(ParameterFactory.CreateParameter("@Taxes", po.Taxes, SqlDbType.Money, ParameterDirection.Input));
            parms.Add(ParameterFactory.CreateParameter("@Total", po.Total, SqlDbType.Money, ParameterDirection.Input));
            parms.Add(ParameterFactory.CreateParameter("@EmployeeId", po.EmployeeId, 8, SqlDbType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input));

            parms.Add(ParameterFactory.CreateParameter("@PONumOut", 12345, SqlDbType.Int, ParameterDirection.Output));

            try
            {
                returnCount = dataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(SPROC_INSERT_PO, CommandType.StoredProcedure, parms);
                if (returnCount >= 0)
                {
                    po.Timestamp = (byte[])parms[0].Value;
                    returnId = Convert.ToInt32(parms[6].Value);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return returnId;
        }
```

```
 public static IParam CreateParameter(string name, object value, SqlDbType type, ParameterDirection direction)
        {
            return new Param(name, value, type, direction);
        }
```

```
        public Param(string name, object value, SqlDbType type, ParameterDirection direction)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
            Size = 0;
            DataType = type;
            Direction = direction;
        }
```

```
        public int ExecuteNonQuery(string cmdText, CommandType cmdType, List<IParam> parms)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand(cmdText, cmdType, parms);

            using (cmd.Connection)
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

```
        public SqlCommand CreateCommand(string cmdText, CommandType cmdType, List<IParam> parms)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
                Properties.Settings.Default.cnnString);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = cmdType;

            if (parms != null)
            {
                foreach (IParam p in parms)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(p.Name,
                        p.DataType, p.Size));
                    cmd.Parameters[p.Name].Value = p.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters[p.Name].Direction = p.Direction;
                }
            }

            return cmd;
        }
```

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertPO]
    @Timestamp timestamp OUTPUT,
    @Status Int,
    @Subtotal money,
    @Taxes money,
    @Total money,
    @EmployeeId varchar(8),
    @PONumOut Int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT OFF
        INSERT INTO
            PurchaseOrder(Status,Subtotal,Taxes,Total,EmployeeId)
        VALUES
            (@Status, @Subtotal, @Taxes, @Total, @EmployeeId)

        SET @PONumOut = @@IDENTITY;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        THROW
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: "ParameterFactory" looks to be 3rd party?  if so that's where the problem probably resides.  You can always run a Trace in the Profiler and see exactly what SQL ends up being sent to the server, that can often provide clues as to whats wrong.

Comment: Are we speaking of `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace?

Comment: @MilenkoJevremovic Yes, it is using System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: Than `ExecuteNonQuery` definitely doesn't return ID, check the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I edited the answer, so check the solution @JeremyLirette

Comment: Can you confirm that the table you're inserting into has an identity column? (Unrelated - change `throw ex` to just `throw`, or even remove the try/catch altogether. If all you're doing is catching and rethrowing then `throw ex` is worse than nothing because you lose information about where the exception actually occurred.)

Comment: @ScottHannen the table does have an identity column. When I run the stored procedure in SQL Server, it returns the new id correctly.

Comment: post the code of `ParameterFactory.CreateParameter`.   Without it, your issue is unreproducible and off-topic for SO.   You'll need to post the code of `dataAccess` while you're at it.

Comment: @TabAlleman code for ParameterFactory.CreateParameter and dataAccess has been added.

Comment: You try to read the output as `parms[6].Value` which is the value of a `Parm` object not the `SqlParameter` you created from it in `CreateCommand()`.  The `Parm` object is never assigned the output value from an `SqlParameter` so is always null.  Perhaps consider removing this abstraction entirely as currently it does not seem to offer anything, if you want cross database functionality there are the `IDbxxx` interfaces.

Comment: This code looks like it *could* work, but I'm not so sure about the implementation of `parameterDirection`.   I would put a breakpoint on the line `return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and peek closely into the parameters collection to see if anything looks amiss.   If that doesn't reveal the answer, then I would run a profiler trace on the SQL Server to see what SQL Command is actually being sent by the application.

Comment: @TabAlleman I have found the issue. See my answer to the question below.

Comment: FWIW, adding wrappers around stuff like SQL commands can sometimes be more trouble than it's worth. It hides the inner behavior, but you still end up writing about as much code. The code just looks different because you're interacting with the wrapper instead of the framework classes. Then everyone who works on the code needs to get used to a different wrapper. If we just work with the framework classes then we get more experience with them and it's easier for other people (like on SO) to look at our code and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.

Needed to modify my ExecuteNonQuery() method to the following.

```
        public int ExecuteNonQuery(string cmdText, CommandType cmdType, List<IParam> parms)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = CreateCommand(cmdText, cmdType, parms);

            using (cmd.Connection)
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                int ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                UnloadParms(parms, cmd);
                return ret;
            }
        }
```

And add the following method.

```
private static void UnloadParms(List<IParam> parms, SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            if (parms != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= parms.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    IParam p = parms[i];
                    p.Value = cmd.Parameters[i].Value;
                    parms[i] = p;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please used like this

`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertPO]
    @Timestamp timestamp OUTPUT,
    @Status Int,
    @Subtotal money,
    @Taxes money,
    @Total money,
    @EmployeeId varchar(8),
    @PONumOut Int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT OFF
        INSERT INTO
            PurchaseOrder(Status,Subtotal,Taxes,Total,EmployeeId)
        VALUES
            (@Status, @Subtotal, @Taxes, @Total, @EmployeeId)

```
    SET @PONumOut = @@IDENTITY;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW
END CATCH
```

return @PONumOut;`

END